# Automatically marshall JSON in Camel

Tags: java, json, jaxb, apache-camel

Apache camel seems to be quite happy marshalling JAXB annotated classes, e.g.:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "authPlayerRequest")
public class AuthPlayerRequest {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Player player;
}
```

If this is on a `servlet://...` route then this works just fine.

However... I want JSON. This does not appear to work automatically and I cannot figure out how to get it to work.

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Have you tried https://camel.apache.org/json.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the JSON handler and sometimes give it a hint to the annotated class.

```
<dataFormats>
    <json id="pojo" library="Jackson" unmarshalTypeName="com.co.Pojo"/>
</dataFormats>

<route id="myRouteUsingJson">
    <from uri="..." />
    <unmarshal ref="pojo" />
    <bean ref="myClassThatNeedAPojo" method="doStuffPojoAsParameter" />
...
```